# Edit CSS Like Dreamweaver

Tags: css, aptana, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver, there is a window, usually on the right, containing all the bits of css properties in the current css file.

I'm sure this is in Aptana, but I can't seem to find how to turn it on.

Further, is there a way to click on the CSS property and bring up the editing menu box, like Dreamweaver? To me, it made things much faster than trying to remember everything and coding by hand.

Comment: Then you're in the wrong place (see: http://superuser.com).

Comment: I'm confused. Why does Aptana link to this site, for community support?

Comment: Maybe because they are subscribed to `aptana`-tagged questions? I don't know; I don't have anything to do with Aptana (or, is it Appcelerator?).

Comment: Hummm... There are 575 other posts with Aptana tags, 17, this week. Superuser.com only has 15 in the entire year.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Maybe I'm wrong, but how to configure settings/preferences in a software application is only related to programming (according to the software's use), it is not *programming related*. **Edit** - And I could be wrong. I generally haven't seen these types of questions on SO.

Comment: *software tools commonly used by programmers* - This could entirely fit into that, depending on the interpretation. Regardless, someone with Aptana experience would need to answer. Why they link here for customer support, I don't know, but without an Aptana tag, I would be skeptical they would know, and there are a *lot* more non-Aptana folk here than Aptana-qualified support people, since this is not an Aptana support forum. It doesn't really have anything to do with DW or CSS specifically.

Comment: In the FAQ, under the first section, "What kind of questions can I ask here?" it says "software tools commonly used by programmers" I'm new to Aptana, but, as far as I understand, it's a software tool, commonly used by programmers... 

Unless you're saying I can't ask here, because it's not PHP, ASP, Java, etc?

I felt it would be a good place to start, since I've been Googling the question, all day.

Comment: *tools* could be interpreted as *programmatic tools* like a library, api, or other *programming-related tool*. That said, a loose interpretation would lend itself to your assertion, sure. I'm not *blaming you*, understand, for anything. SO is not an Aptana support forum, it's a programmer's Q/A site.

Comment: Also, I believe you may be looking for Outlines in Eclipse: http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-305.html Aptana Studio is an Eclipse-based editor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the outline? It's in the lower-left corner by default, or you can Window > Show View > Outline.

For the second bit, there is no editing menu box, but you can ctrl + space inside a CSS rule and it will show you available properties.